# JPA NativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA.

I have created a JPA native query based on `3 tables ping,ting and ming`

```
Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("select p.value1,m.value2,t.value3,p.id,m.id from ping as p,ming as m,ting as t where p.id=m.vid and m.id=t.vid");

List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

I have successfully obtained the results.

All the values are fine except that the values of `p.id = m.id` at each row.

It looks like `m.id` and `p.id` are picking up the values of `p.id` when run using native query.

I have tried the above query on mysql prompt and values of `p.id!=m.id` and are as expected.

How an I get `m.id's` actual value.

Comment: Your query doesn't even select m.id. How could it be equal to anything? Why do you use SQL instead of JPQL?

Comment: @JBNizet edited.Actually the query has to be written over many entities.So I have gone for SQL

Comment: JPQL supports joins. Learn it. If p.id is equal to m.if for each row, then either that's indeed the case, or there is a bug in the code. Post it.

Comment: Can you please post the source code for the JPA Entities that you have defined for ping, ming and ting? Also, can you post the definitions of the database tables? This would probably be a very simple JPA query if the Entities are defined correctly.